# Nuxt3 deploy error in Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: typescript, azure, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to run nuxt3 out-of-the-box in Azure Static Web Apps, but it always runs into error about @nuxt/kit not installed.
It's just for my own study, I did almost the same in Vercel with React+Next and it works like a charm

Steps:

Created an Azure Static App for node, linked to github

Created nuxt app: (npx nuxi init nuxt3-app) https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation

Changed output in workflow yml: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/deployment/azure

Created empty .gitkeep inside output/server

Repo:
https://github.com/betonogueira/pessoalnuxt3

PS: If I install and then uninstall @nuxt/kit the same error begin to occur in development environment

```
Running 'npm run build'...


> @ build /github/workspace
> nuxt build

[log] Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-27238235.a1bcc53
[error] nuxi requires `@nuxt/kit` to be installed in your project. Try installing `nuxt3` or 
`@nuxt/bridge` first.
  at loadKit (node_modules/nuxt3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/kit.mjs:44:13)
  at Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxt3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/build.mjs:23:43)
  at _main (node_modules/nuxt3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/index.mjs:417:17)
```

Comment: Trying with React/Next is totally irrelevant so far. What about the following error? `Try installing nuxt3 or @nuxt/bridge first.` Did you tried something with it?

Comment: Hi @kissu, the another try was just to say "i did it before", nevermind kk... I've installed nuxt3 and push changes to git, still the same problem.

Comment: Try not to add this as a dev dependency tho.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm seeing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Web Apps do not work right now, but if you deploy it to an Azure Function, it does work there. I beat my head against this the last few days.

Essentially... Static Web Apps do not have a high enough Node version right now.

Comment: Yes, thats it... When I wrote this question I still didn't have the update in the official documentation.

Comment: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/deployment/azure